# setting IFS='@' in bash script

Tags: bash, sh

In Bash

I am splitting a variable on the basis of IFS as

```
        while IFS='@' read -r uuid
        do
            echo --"$uuid"--
        done <<< abcd@sasa@assa
        IFS=$OIFS
```

but same piece of code is not splitting the string  abcd@sasa@assa according to IFS .

Do not able to resolve the issue

Comment: No need to reset IFS to OIFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `read -ra`:

```
IFS=@ read -ra arr <<< 'abcd@sasa@assa'

printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
abcd
sasa
assa
```